Proof that $\forall \alpha \in \mathbf{ON}(L(\alpha) \cap \mathbf{ON}) = \alpha$.
In Kunens "Set Theory An Introduction to Independence Proofs", lemma 1.9.(b), he proves the following:

$\forall \alpha \in \mathbf{ON}(L(\alpha) \cap \mathbf{ON}) = \alpha$.

Now, the proof proceeds by induction. When we come to the successor-case, we want to show that $\beta$ in $L(\beta)$.
Now Kunen proceeds by then saying that:

Recall (IV 5.1) that there is a $\Delta_0$-formula $\phi(x)$ such that $$\forall x(\text{$x$ is an ordinal} \leftrightarrow \phi(x)).$$ Since $\Delta_0$-formulas are absolute for all transitive sets, $$\beta = L(\beta) \cap \mathbf{ON} = \{x \in L(\beta): \phi^{L(\beta)}(x)\}, \qquad (1)$$ so $\beta \in \mathscr{D}(L(\beta)) = L(\alpha)$ by lemma 1.2. $ \quad \square$

Now, when we actually look at theorem 5.1 in IV, it says:

The following relations and functions were defined in $\sf{ZF}-\sf{P}$ by formulas provably equivalent in $\sf{ZF}-\sf{P}$ to $\Delta_0$-formulas. $\underline{\text{They are thus absolute for transitive models of $\sf{ZF}-\sf{P}$}}$ (my underlining).

$x$ is an ordinal.
$\ldots$.


But does this not mean that we need $L(\beta)$ to be a model for $\sf{ZF}-\sf{P}$ to assert that $\phi^{L(\beta)}(x) \leftrightarrow \phi(x)$, which seems to be what Kunen is using in $(1)$? If yes, as far as I can see, he has not proved this before lemma 1.9.(b) in VI. What he has proved, is that $L(\beta)$ is transitive (see lemma 1.6.(a) in VI).
So why is the step $\phi(x) \rightarrow \phi^{L(\beta)}(x)$ motivated?
Any clarification would be appreciated.
Addendum: My suspicion is that Kunen is using corollary 3.6, IV, which says:

If $\mathbf{M}$ is transitive, and $\phi$ is $\Delta_0$, then $\phi$ is absolute for $\mathbf{M}$.

I am however unsure how this result fits in with lemma 5.1, IV (partially quoted above).

There's no need to analyze what axioms hold in $L(\beta).$ You just need to show that $$\beta=\{x\in L(\beta): \phi(x)\}\in L(\beta+1),$$ where $\phi(x)$ says $x$ is transitive and linearly ordered by $\in.$ We know that $\phi$ defines the ordinals in $V,$ and that's enough.
Now, since $\phi$ is (syntactically) $\Delta_0,$ it is absolute for any transitive model of anything and we have $\phi^{L(\beta)}(x) \leftrightarrow\phi(x)$ for $x\in L(\beta)$ so $$\{x\in L(\beta): \phi(x)\}= \{x\in L(\beta): \phi^{L(\beta)}(x)\}\in L(\beta+1).$$

That said, I think ZF-P vastly overstates what is needed for the equivalence of "$x$ is transitive and well-ordered by $\in$" and "$x$ is transitive and linearly-ordered by $\in$". I believe that literally only requires foundation, so the equivalence should hold in any transitive model.

So part of what you are saying in the last paragraph before your addendum, is really what I said (AFAICT) in my addendum, i.e. Kunen uses the fact that any $\Delta_0$-formula is absolute for a transitive class (cor. 3.6)?
What I am however still confused about, is then why is $\mathbf{M}$ being a model for $\sf{ZF}-\sf{P}$ needed in theorem 5.1 (IV) (yes, there are also other statements there, besides "$x$ being an ordinal")?

Oh, right, if we don't have foundation, we don't know that $x$ is well-ordered by $\in$.

@Ben123 Per my last paragraph I think just foundation is needed in the background and then "$x$ is an ordinal" is equivalent to $\phi(x)$ in any transitive set or class, but I'm less sure of that than I am that he's only using that it's equivalent to $\phi(x)$ in $V$ in the argument.

I don't understand what you mean, tbh. You have not confirmed whether you agree with the fact that he uses cor. 3.6, so I don't know if that is what you mean, or something else.

@Ben123 He is using that "$x$ is an ordinal" is provably equivalent to the $\Delta_0$ formula $\phi(x)$ by axioms that hold in $V$... i.e. he is only using that $V$ satsifies ZF-P. Nowhere is it asserted or used that the equivalence holds in $L(\beta).$

@Ben123 Yes, he is just using absoluteness of syntactically $\Delta_0$ formulas to get $\phi(x)\leftrightarrow \phi^{L(\beta)}(x).$ He is using both 5.1 and 3.6, though he doesn't explicitly reference the latter, just says "Since $\Delta_0$
-formulas are absolute for all transitive sets."
